# Cant open programs without terminal

Tags: permissions, 15.10

I can not open programs which need root acces without using terminal.

Example:
When I click Firefox on my desktop, nothing happens.
I have to type `sudo firefox` to browse the internet.

I think this has something to do with permissions, but I am a bit new.

Running Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit.

Edit:
Typing only `firefox` in the terminal gives this:

> Could not create gnome accelerators directory '`/home/juho/.gnome2/accels`':
>   Permission denied

Comment: **never** use `sudo` with a Web browser. You must have your `PATH` badly set. Open a terminal, type `firefox` (no `sudo`!) and report what's happening; type `echo $PATH` and do the same (please edit the question, don't add it as comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you messed up some file ownerships while running GUI applications as root using `sudo`. The following command should fix this and give you back the ownership of all files in your home directory:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```

Hope this fixes it.

---

**For the future:**

**Never** run GUI programs as root using `sudo` - always use `gksudo` or at least `sudo -H` to avoid such problems to come back.
You should run programs as root as rarely as possible anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Getting the ownership of my home directory fixed the issue. Thanks for the tip about `sudo` too :)